# iOS how to sort NSMutableArray of custom object contained NSarray of NSNumber?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nssortdescriptor

I have an array `(NSMutableArray)` which contains StudentScoreObj and the object have `missions` `(NSArray)`.

Like:

```
missions = @[@34, @43, @54, @23, @54];
```

> need to sort StudentScoreObj of array using first object of missions array.

My code:

```
@interface StudentScoreObj : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *teamType;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *teamNumber;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *studentName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *isParticipated ;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *totalScore;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *avgScore;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *missions;

@end
```

Comment: How have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sorted​Array​Using​Comparator`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsarray/1411195-sortedarrayusingcomparator) for that.

```
NSArray *sortArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(StudentScoreObj *obj1,StudentScoreObj  *obj2) {

    NSNumber *obj1Score = @0, *obj2Score = @0;        
    if([[obj1 missions] firstObject]) {
        obj1Score = @([[[obj1 missions] firstObject] intValue]);
    }

    if([[obj2 missions] firstObject]) {
        obj2Score = @([[[obj2 missions] firstObject] intValue]);
    }
    return [obj1Score compare:obj2Score];
}];
```

Comment: @PillowPig Welcome mate :)